# Uploading an image to mongodb is not saving

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to upload an image to my mongodb database but it is not saving. My mongoose schema is like this:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  picture: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
});
```

I noticed another thing that I am sending the picture like this :
`picture: 'C:\\fakepath\\6b512998.jpg'` This entire thing is reaching my server as a string after that my database doesn't save the picture but only title gets saved.

```
router.post('/post', function(req, res) {
  Post.create(req.body, function(err, post) {
  });
});
```

I am not getting any errors on my console.

edit: I was thinking it was more of a schema fault. Here is the form.
I am not sure about middle wear. How do I check that? Sorry I am still new and learning new everyday.

new.html:

```
 <form class="imageform" action="posts" method="/post" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg"> 
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <input type="file" name="picture"><br>
  <button type="submit"> Submit form </button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should show what multipart middleware you're using and how you're configuring it. Most likely your file(s) are on `req.files` instead of `req.body` if your form was submitted correctly. You may want to show how you are submitting the form too (including html if you're doing it that way).

Comment: Solved this problem for front end by using multer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to convert your image files to another format, before saving them to the database,

If your files are actually less than 16 mb, please try using this Converter that changes the image of format jpeg / png to a format of saving to mongodb, and you can see this as an easy alternative for gridfs ,

[please check this github repo for more details...](https://github.com/saran-surya/Mongo-Image-Converter)